# R extract education degree with str_match_all

Tags: r, stringr

I have an R string column containing education information (university + degree). I would like to extract the degree and creating two categorial variables to indicate undergraduate or graduate degree (`undergrad.dummy` and `grad.dummy`).

```
df = data.frame(educ = c("Angelo State University  (BBA, Finance; BBA, Economics;)", "University of Oxford  (MA, Philosophy; MA, Economics;", "Ross School of Business, University of Michigan  (MBA; BBA;)"))
```

My approach is to create a list of undergrad and graduate degree, like below

```
undergrad.list = c("BBA", "BA")
grad.list = c("MA", "MBA", "PhD")
```

What I attempted is to first extract the degree from `educ`

```
df$degree = str_match_all(df$educ, "BBA|MS|MBA|BA")
```

The problem is the result can be a vector, and I'm having difficult time to extract undergrad and grad degree from that for my large dataset. In the end, I'd like to have

```
df = data.frame(educ = c("Angelo State University  (BBA, Finance; BBA, Economics;)", "University of Oxford  (MA, Philosophy; MA, Economics;", "Ross School of Business, University of Michigan  (MBA; BBA;)"), undergrad.dummy = c(1,0,1), grad.dummy = c(0,1,1))
```

Hope to get some suggestions to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the pattern vectors in a `list`, loop over the `list` with `map` (from `purrr`), `paste` them into a single string by `collapse`ing with `|` (`OR`) use that in `pattern` within `str_detect`, returns a logical vector, coerce it to binary (`as.integer` or `+`), rename the columns from `map_dfc` and bind those columns to original dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map_dfc(list(undergrad.list, grad.list), ~
       +(str_detect(df$educ, str_c("\\b(",str_c(.x, collapse="|"), ")\\b")))) %>%
   set_names(c("undergrad.dummy", 'grad.dummy')) %>%
  bind_cols(df, .)
```

-output

```
#                                                          educ undergrad.dummy grad.dummy
#1     Angelo State University  (BBA, Finance; BBA, Economics;)               1          0
#2        University of Oxford  (MA, Philosophy; MA, Economics;               0          1
#3 Ross School of Business, University of Michigan  (MBA; BBA;)               1          1
```

Comment: One problem is that for observations like `Southern Methodist University  (MBA;`, both two dummy variables will return `1`. Do you have any suggestion to deal with such cases?

Comment: @dunguyen i would add word boundary `str_c("\\b(",str_c(.x, collapse="|"), ")\\b")`

Comment: Never mind my question above. I figured to add `\\bMBA\\b` for exact matches. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
      if (grepl("BA", df$educ[i]) == TRUE) {
        df$unddummy[i] <- 1
      } else {
        df$unddummy[i] <- 0
      }
      if (grepl("MBA|MA|Phd", df$educ[i]) == TRUE) {
        df$graddummy[i] <- 1
      } else {
        df$graddummy[i] <- 0
      }
    }

 df
                                                          educ unddummy graddummy
1     Angelo State University  (BBA, Finance; BBA, Economics;)        1         0
2        University of Oxford  (MA, Philosophy; MA, Economics;        0         1
3 Ross School of Business, University of Michigan  (MBA; BBA;)        1         1
```

This solution checks the content of a cell in df$edu and puts a corresponding value into unddummy  and graddummy. Two things to notic: when checking the undergraduates, checking for "BA" is enough, because "BBA" contains "BA". This hints to an important problem and my regex skills are close to nonexistent. This code will also mark a university as "undergraduate" when the name contains BA, for example the "University of BAli". Ill edit once I find the corret way to do it with regex ...